# Display multiple dynamic object with for loops in templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

So to summary, my database structure is like this:

```
test
  |_ question
      |_ choice
      |_ choice
      |_ choice
  |_ question
      |_ choice
      |_ choice
      |_ choice
```

Now I want to display all of the choices of each question on a single page.

My `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    data = {
        'greeting': 'Welcome User!',
        'form_test': forms.TestForm,
        'form_question': forms.QuestionForm,
        'form_choice': forms.ChoiceForm,
        'test': models.Test.objects.get(pk=1),
        'questions': models.Question.objects.filter(test_id__exact=1),
    }

    questions = models.Question.objects.filter(test_id=1)

    for question in questions:
        data['choices_{}'.format(question.id)] = models.Choice.objects.filter(question_id=question.id)

    print(data)
    return render(request, 'et_app/index.html', context=data)
```

So technically if I have 2 questions, my `data` would look something like this:

```
{
...
'choices_1': ...
'choices_2': ...
...
}
```

Now, my problem is on displaying these `choices` on the templates. I tried:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <h4>Q: {{ question.content }}</h4>

    <p>Choices:</p>
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for choice in 'choices_{}'.format(question.id) %}
            <li class="list-group-item">{{ choice.content }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

It just broke the whole thing. I'm relatively new to Django so forgive my naiveness. How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

### Update

`models.py`:

```
# Create your models here.
def generate_code():
    return get_random_string(length=7)


class Test(models.Model):
    test_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, editable=False, unique=True, default=generate_code())
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.content, self.question.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no need for manually building the choices context variable in the first place (the part `data['choices_{}'.format(question.id)]`).

You would only need to do something like this in your template:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <h4>Q: {{ question.content }}</h4>

    <p>Choices:</p>
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            <li class="list-group-item">{{ choice.content }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The key part is `question.choice_set.all`; Django automatically builds reverse relationship accessors. See the doc: [Making queries: Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).